# Triangle Inequality on Quotient Norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E/F$ be a quotient space where $E$ ,$F$ are normed spaces with $F \subset E$. 
I am trying to show that norm defined by $ || [x] || = \inf \{\lvert \lvert x-f\rvert\rvert : f \in F  \}  $  on $E/F$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

(Note that $[x]   $ means equivalence class of x where equivalence relation is defined by $ y \in [x] \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x-y \in F \quad $ )

I proceeded as follows:

$$\lvert\lvert [x]+[y]   \rvert\rvert = \inf \{ \lvert\lvert [x]+[y]-f  \rvert\rvert: f \in F   \}   $$
$$   \leq \inf \{ \lvert\lvert[x]-f   \rvert\rvert + || [y] -f || + ||f|| : f\in F  \} $$

when I take the norm of f as zero in the above set , I make this extra term disappear, But this time I cannot assure the other norms will take the inf norm. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 5):

For any $f_1,f_2\in F$, we have
$$\|[x]+[y]\|_{E/F}\,\le\,\|x+f_1\,+\,y+f_2\|_E\,\le\,
\|x+f_1\|_E\, +\,\|y+f_2\|_E\,.$$
Now take infinum first for all $f_1\in F$, then for all $f_2\in F$.